# Build postgreSQL in Windows with Python

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, postgresql-9.2

Can i install and build postgreSQL from Source Code in Windows by using Python? Is it solid? Currently in their **documentation** they have [Visual C++ as their only option!](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/install-windows.html)

And if it is possible (and reliable) where can i find prime material to use Python to build and customize my postgreSQL? I won't go and learn Visual C++ unless it is the only way. I also have GitBash if that helps...

---

For people who have no idea on db's. They never say that in documentations because they think it for granted.

**IT ALL BOILS DOWN TO: It is another thing building_from_source/installing a db and a totally another thing interacting/working with a db.**

Comment: Could you clarify your question?  Are you wanting to work with a PostgreSQL database from python?  Or are you actually trying to build Postgre from source?

Comment: I want to actually interact and work with PostgreSQL with python and work with. Not install it using Python.

Comment: Please to not use backticks to emphasize non-code.

Comment: @Alexandros yes you are right i am going to remove it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is library for accessing Postgres from python called [psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/).  There is a tutorial on its use [here](http://zetcode.com/db/postgresqlpythontutorial/).

To the extent that you are just learning about databases, you might also take a look at [Sqlite](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/), which is a more lightweight database and included in the python standard library

Comment: To install it with Visual C++ it's a whole different thing from interacting with it. Right? I didnt know that i am totally knew on db's

Comment: Right, the link you referenced is about building the Postgre application from source - for you purposes you'll likely just want to install the binaries. http://www.postgresql.org/download/

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use PostgreSQL you really don't need to compile anything. Simply [install PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/) and the windows binaries of [psycopg2](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/) (the PostgreSQL client library for python).

If you want to *build* the PostgreSQL database server - something you only want/need to do if you want to modify PostgreSQL itself, and which is something you probably don't want to do as a beginner - you should use whatever compiler the Postgres developers suggest since they most likely only have project/make files for that compiler.

Comment: i have installed postgresql with an installer (exe) can i interact with postgresql from the Python Shell? (of course after i install the module aforementioned)

Comment: Yes. Just `import psycopg2`. For more details check the package's documentation. However, if you just want to send SQL queries it's much besser to use the *psql* commandline client or *pgAdmin III* GUI client.

Comment: Yup i only want to send commands for SQL Queries. I tried to make it interact with Windows because there are no tutorials to explain how to operate from the GUI. I am starting to suspect that SQL is one language that can be used for all the db programs. Is that the case? If it is it will be quite a revelation for me!

Comment: Wow my first searches show that this might be it. If it is the same for all db programs i (logically) can easily locate training material.

Comment: FYI, if you want to stay (mostly) database-independent, have a look at SQLAlchemy.